# Ubuntu 18.04 drag-and-drop icons to sidebar fails to bring window to foreground

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, drag-and-drop

I've noticed another useful feature that used to exist in Ubuntu, but seems to have disappeared in the 18.04 upgrade.

If you drag an icon (e.g. a file or a web link) to the sidebar, so that the pointer is hovering over an open application, that application used to immediately pop into the foreground.

This allowed you to easily drag-and-drop to a window that is not currently visible, in one smooth action, and was particularly useful when you have another app filling the screen.

Can I re-enable this useful feature in 18.04?